# Can't connect to smtp.gmail.com on port 465 or 587

Tags: 14.04, networking, iptables, firewall, smtp

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 (*Trusty Tahr*) is mounted on AWS and i cannot connect to the SMTP GMail service vía:

**SSL(*465*)**:

```
## $ telnet smtp.gmail.com 465 ##
Trying 74.125.28.109...
Trying 74.125.28.108...
Trying 2607:f8b0:400e:c04::6c... 
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

**TLS(*587*):**

```
## $ telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 ##
Trying 74.125.28.108...
Trying 74.125.28.109...
Trying 2607:f8b0:400e:c04::6c...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

My open ports are:

```
## $ sudo netstat -tlnp ##
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1069/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1050/redis-server 1
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      959/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      7716/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      959/sshd
```

The UFW Firewall are inactive

```
## $ sudo ufw status verbose ##
Status: inactive
```

I already saved the firewall rules with:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 587 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables-save
```

Comment: Are you able to get to other web sites using a web browser (Firefox) and an email program (Thunderbird)? Or do you have larger network problems?

Comment: @heynnema Is a Ubuntu Server loaded inside an AWS.
I can use "apt-get", "wget" etc, but i cannot connect to the Gmail SMTP service.

Comment: If you Google "AWS SMTP" you'll see that AWS provides SMTP services, so they may be blocking your direct access to smtp.gmail.com. Something to check into.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, VPS machine without firewall and with same error as you listed. I contacted support of VPS provider and it turned out they had one more firewall that was wrapping my machine. So they enabled port 587 on that firewall and everything was working smoothly.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a firewall problem. I faced a similar problem in Ubuntu (Digital Ocean server). I tried to fix the issue for 3 days. I equally tried using auth2, and finally checked the Digital Ocean admin panel and created a firewall for the droplet.

The problem was solved by enabling TCP inbound and outbound in the firewall settings.